# Undeclared reference to constructor of derived classes

Tags: c++

I have a number of objects, all of which have constructors that take no parameters. I defined the simple constructor of the base class, and I have not defined the others.  When compiling, I receive an "Undeclared reference to constructor" error for each class, but I get an even more confusing error if I try to define the derived objects' constructors.
The following is the "weird" error:

```
CMakeFiles/project4.dir/src/Strategy.cpp.o: In function `ForwardStrategy':
/home/ics45c/projects/p4/src/Strategy.cpp:42: undefined reference to `vtable for
ForwardStrategy'
```

My constructor for the base class looks like this:

```
ForwardStrategy::ForwardStrategy()
{
}
```

And all other constructors look like this (each with different numbers):

```
ForwardStrategy1::ForwardStrategy1()
{
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Edit: Here is the class declaration:

```
class ForwardStrategy
{
public:
    ForwardStrategy();
    virtual ~ForwardStrategy() = default;
    virtual bool isWorthForwarding(Message::Message* m) = 0;
    virtual void setType(unsigned int type);
    virtual void setQuality(unsigned int q);
private:
    unsigned int type;
    unsigned int quality;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your non-pure virtual methods are implemented somewhere and are being linked. See [**GCC FAQ**](http://gcc.gnu.org/faq.html#vtables):

> Therefore, if you fail to define this particular method, the linker may complain about the lack of definitions for apparently unrelated symbols...
>
> The solution is to ensure that all virtual methods that are not pure are defined. Note that a destructor must be defined even if it is declared pure-virtual.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am still confused on _which_ methods to define. My base class declares 5 methods: a constructor, a destructor, two voids, and a bool.  The constructor is declared as follows:

    ForwardStrategy()

And the other methods:
    virtual ~ForwardStrategy() = default;
    virtual bool isWorthForwarding(Message::Message* m) = 0;
    virtual void setType(unsigned int type);
    virtual void setQuality(unsigned int q);

I will post them above to make them more readable.

Comment: Add it to your question please, stop trying to fit everything in a comment.

Comment: Done. My apologies, I'm new to this site, and I'm still figuring out how to correctly format things.

Comment: Provide an implementation for `setType` and `setQuality` or make them pure virtual too `=0`.

Comment: I believe I have isolated the problem but can you attempt to quickly explain why this is? When I comment out the destructor of my base class, it compiles. Simply declaring it as virtual, or setting it equal to default causes it to fail.

Comment: @MattDella it's a restriction placed on using `=default` on a virtual destructor. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/824185/234175). The new C++14 draft seems to allow it but in the meantime just give it an empty body `{}` instead.